# mapping local folder to within container doesn't show any files

Tags: docker, ubuntu, permissions, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have a custom image built whose [gist is here](https://gist.github.com/aino-gautam/b657c2967563ac801c37cec3608e7b96) .

when I run this image using the below command

```
docker run --name tf-flask -it -v ${pwd}/flask:/tf-train/flask-temp ainosoft/tf-od-2.13-opencv-4.81 bash
```

though the local folder i.e. flask reflects within the container in expected /tf-train/flask-temp, it doesn't show any files within the folder from the local system. I believe its some kind of permissions issue but the local folder has permissions such as

`drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 Oct  3 19:24 flask`

the image swithches to a default user od which is part of sudo group.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The `docker run` command doesn't seem to have a `-p` option, so you won't be able to access the Flask application from outside its container, and also you're specifying a `bash` container override which means the default image `CMD` to launch the Flask server won't run.  It would help to edit the question to include what code is trying to access the files and what result you're actually getting.

Comment: Permissions are checked using the hosts permissions. They're mapped using userid and groupid numbers and *not* the names. So the userid of the `od` user in the image is used when checking. E.g. if the UID of the `od` user is 900, then permissions are checked using UID 900 on the host. And that might be a different user.

Comment: @DavidMaze think the GIST takes care of this requirement ?   I want to run the flask app within docker and expose a port where I access the url. HansKilian.. thanks that seems to be the issue. I managed to check match of userid / groupid and the issue is solved.